# Serverless.com with Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a really simple setup for my [Serverless](http://serverless.com) application that uses NodeJS.  Everything builds just find in [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) except for the deployment through the standard command of `serverless deploy`, where I get the following error message:

> User: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/bitbucket-build-user is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResources on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:my-region: 123456789012:stack/mylambda-dev/*

Locally it works just fine.  Here's the *Pipelines* configuration:

```
image:
  name: mydocker/serverless-docker:latest
  username: $MY_DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME
  password: $MY_DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
  email: $MY_DOCKER_HUB_EMAIL

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run lint

  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - npm install
            - npm run lint
            - serverless config credentials --overwrite --provider aws --key $MY_AWS_KEY --secret $MY_AWS_SECRET
            - serverless deploy
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Serverless uses AWS CloudFormation for a full deploy (the one you do with `serverless deploy`), the *bitbucket-build-user* has to have certain permissions to manage CloudFormation stacks. So at the bare minimum, you'll need a to attach a policy that looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:Describe*",
                "cloudformation:List*",
                "cloudformation:Get*",
                "cloudformation:PreviewStackUpdate",
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
}
```

Take a look at https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1439 to get an idea what permissions *bitbucket-build-user* might need.

Personally, I just use https://github.com/dancrumb/generator-serverless-policy to generate those policies instead of writing them manually every time.

Comment: It's odd that it works locally, though.  I imported my AWS credentials to the build image and my own local user does not have access, either.  I use a `export AWS_PROFILE=aws_lambda` locally and was trying to emulate that in my Docker image.  I will definitely try this, though.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks.